# Run SQL-like queries across large JSON datasets, in the cloud?

Tags: json, google-bigquery, apache-drill, bigdata

Is there a product that meets these requirements:

- running SQL-like queries (preferably with a friendly UI, though can use command line if necessary)
- across largely static JSON datasets of several million documents, without a consistent schema
- with the JSON documents stored in the cloud, not locally.

Basically, I would like Google BigQuery, but without the requirement for a consistent pre-specified schema.

Apache Drill offers SQL-like queries across large JSON datasets with different schemas. However, I don't think it works well on cloud-hosted datasets - have set it up to talk to an S3 bucket, and it seems to need to download all the data locally, which makes it unusable with large datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery requires a static schema, but one option is to define the tables as CSV with a separator that doesn't appear in the data, meaning you'd have a single string column. You'll be limited to the `JSON_EXTRACT` functions for pulling data from the JSON, but from there you can cast to other data types and so on.

You could also consider [filing a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) for the BigQuery team to consider supporting a document type to make working with this kind of data easier in the future.